# Can IIS server in .NET Core deploy Kestrel servers on multiple hosts?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I know that with .NET Core when you "publish" to IIS, it works as a reverse-proxy, routing messages to Kestrel servers, and ensures they stay alive. However, I haven't seen anywhere defined, are all these Kestrel servers deployed on the same host as the IIS server, or can the IIS server be on one host, and deploy the Kestrel servers on separate and individual hosts with their own IP addresses?

If not, then what is the deployment strategy in production? Each VM needs to have their own IIS, deploying 1-n Kestrels? Then you would need a separate e.g. F5 load-balancer on top of the IIS servers?

Thanks for any input on this :)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core [middleware for IIS integration](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs#L38) expect that IIS and application are deployed on the same machine:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseIISIntegration(this IWebHostBuilder app)
{
    ...
    var address = "http://localhost:" + port + path;
    app.UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ServerUrlsKey, address);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is so disappointing... this means that production deployments with Kestrel will be again old-school, as always done before... So one VM hosts one IIS and one Kestrel

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use Kestrel to self-host w/o the IIS (just remove the `UseIISIntegration` and listen on a non-loopback IP), but it shouldn't be an internet facing application (its not ready for that yet). But you have to configure your IIS manually to route/balance the request to the ips/services behind. There is no "automatic service discovery" provided. Also you'll need to manage the lifecycle yourself (i.e. the application won't be stopped/restarted by IIS anymore).

But since in microservices/scalable scenarios the IPs are not fixed and may change when services spawn and despawn, it's a bit tricky with IIS there as you'd need to change this configuration as the new services start and stop.

So if you work with microservices you'll have to use some thing like ZooKeeper from the java world (basically a key-value store where each webservice registers there with it's up and you use the values to broadcast/route the requests to) or etcd, maybe even redis.

Maybe have a look at Service Fabric, it can be used on premises too (something along the lines of [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend/)).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping that MS would have taken the direction of being able to remotely deploy Kestrel. I would expect them to do that in the future... now it will be a funny structure: Load Balancer -> IIS -> Kestrel. An one IIS/Kestrel combination for each VM. Is there any point of deploying multiple Kestrels being one IIS then? Or only One Kestrel behind an IIS?